# Suffix "clone.44" on e1000_tx_queue in e1000 device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

e1000_tx_queue is the function in e1000 linux device driver. When I dump the module of e1000 to assembly code, this function is demonstrated as e1000_tx_queue.clone.44. Like:

```
00000c10 <e1000_tx_queue.clone.44>:
 c10:   55                      push   %ebp
 c11:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 c13:   57                      push   %edi
 c14:   56                      push   %esi
 c15:   53                      push   %ebx
 c16:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 c19:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   c1a <e1000_tx_queue.clone.44+0xa>
        c1a: R_386_PC32 mcount
 c1e:   89 45 ec                mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
 c21:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 c24:   89 55 e8                mov    %edx,-0x18(%ebp)
 c27:   a8 04                   test   $0x4,%al
 c29:   0f 84 ad 00 00 00       je     cdc <e1000_tx_queue.clone.44+0xcc>
 c2f:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
 c31:   83 e2 08                and    $0x8,%edx
 c34:   83 fa 01                cmp    $0x1,%edx
 c37:   19 ff                   sbb    %edi,%edi
 c39:   81 e7 00 ff ff ff       and    $0xffffff00,%edi
 <MORE>
```

So what does the suffix "clone.44" mean in this case? Is this added by compiler and what is the usage?
Thanks

Comment: This could be related to "function cloning" used by GCC during code optimization. The [description of `-fipa-cp-clone` and `-fipa-cp` GCC options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) may give some hints. I am not sure though what `.44` means in this case, some kind of an index of the clone or something else.

Comment: [This explanation](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-10/msg00279.html) could also be helpful.